# Xcode 7 beta build fails when attempting to use Squeal

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, xcode7

My Xcode (7 beta) build fails when trying to use [Squeal's](https://github.com/nerdyc/Squeal) library. Its a brand new project with no additional code, and I followed the directions off of the Github page. However, Xcode still fails the build, and shows no errors as to why. Im severely confused. I even added the libraries for `libsqlite3.tdb` and `libsqlite3.0.tbd`and still fail.  Should I try to create a dummy project in Xcode 6 and try it?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found that he just posted a Swift 2 compatible version under the Swift2 Branch